# mongoid sortable list grouped by association

Tags: mongoid, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two models Review and Product. Product has many reviews.

Is there a gem with which I can sort reviews belonging to a product? So far I am using mongoid-orderable to sort reviews. But it doesn't have the ability to sort all the reviews of a product.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is Review an embedded document?

You can sort your reviews during the query using [#sort](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html#sorting) based on a field `order` of the collection `Review` or any other field, like `created_at` for example.

`my_product.reviews.order_by(:created_at)`